# Validation of username and password using linq?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, authentication

Using entity framework I am trying to right a authentication routine that allows for checking both password and username but how using linq would I modifie my query to allow checking of both user name and password individually bare in mind I have to use encryption which is why I have the if statment in play.

```
public LoginStatus validateUser(string username, string userPassword)
   {
       var _currentUser = _db.users.FirstOrDefault(a => a.username == username);

       if (_currentUser != null)
       {
           if (isEncryptionEnabled == true)
           {
               string descriptedPassword = encrypt.DecryptRijndael(_currentUser.password, _currentUser.salt.ToString());

               if (descriptedPassword == userPassword)
                   return LoginStatus.ValidUser;
           }
           else
           {
               var _unecryptedUser = _db.users.FirstOrDefault(a => a.username == username && a.password == userPassword);

               if (_unecryptedUser != null)
                   return LoginStatus.ValidEncryptedUser;//zero represents sufcessfull login attempts
           }
       }
       else
       {
           _loginAttempts++;
       }
       return _loginAttempts;
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally it's best to use LINQ to pull back the user record by ID.  If no match,return user not found.  Then check the password matches what's stored in the database.

Also, you are returning an enum and an int at the bottom; shouldn't you return invalidattempt enum value instead or something like that?  Also, it's advisable not to store clear text passwords, and always encrypt.  You can encrypt the value and then check the encrypted values match...

**EDIT:** If you need to return multiple fields, can create a wrapper class:

```
public class Results
{
   public EnumType Status { get; set; }

   //some other fields
}
```

Comment: @Brain Mains what would you suggest  then and when u say by id you mean the uername and what would you suggest that I return in terms of validuser just a bollean value

Comment: Yes, return the record.  If no record, no user exists.  If one record, then check the passwords.  Return a enumeration that's descriptive to the problem (nouser, passwordinvalid, etc.).

Comment: how do i return an enumaration and a record type via one proecdure

Comment: Create a wrapper class, posted above.